# Parsing a message with various special characters and splitting into a list (re and regex) Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, split

I am trying to parse a message that receives the following delimiters (Without quotes):

- Delimiter1: "@@@" - Followed by a message
- Delimiter2: "!!!" - A signal
- Delimiter3: "---" - Followed by a message
- Delimiter4: "###" - Followed by a message
- Delimiter5: "$$$" - Followed by a message

I have so far:

```
import re
mystring = '@@@useradd---userfirstadded###userremoved!!!$$$message'
result = re.split('\\@\@\@|\\!\!\!|\\---|\\#\#\#|\\$\$\$',mystring)
print result
```

My result so far:

```
['', 'useradd', 'userfirstadded', 'userremoved', '', 'message']
```

I want as a result printed to console:

```
['@@@useradd','---userfirstadded','###userremoved','!!!','$$$message']
```

Is this possible using re.split or do I need to use re.find or something a lot better? I have been playing with the re.split delimiters as you can see but maybe you guys have a lot more experience using this functionality within python.

**EDITED Solution #1 Using re (From @thefourtheye):**

Here is the code:

```
import re   
mystring = '@@@useradd---userfirstadd%ed###this is my username@!!!$$$hey whats up how are you??@@@useradd$$$This is my email @gmail.com!!!'
result = re.findall(r'!!!|(?:@|-|#|\$){3}[\w ^]+', mystring)
print result
```

The result printed is as follows:

```
['@@@useradd', '---userfirstadd', '###this is my username', '!!!', '$$$hey whats up how are you', '@@@useradd', '$$$This is my email ', '!!!']
```

**EDITED New specifications:**

Everything works as specified above and more using the following answer below that @thefourtheye has suggested. If there was possibly more functionality to the function as in allowing one or two of the delimiters or more that would be better as if the user wanted to type his email address in a message he would use the @ symbol or a dollar amount with a $ etc. If this isn't possible, I can always add the delimiters with a space before and after or possibly *@@@* to separate using the delimiters in a message or a different type of message. What are your suggestions?

Summary: I would like to add functionality of accepting all characters until hitting exactly the delimiter pattern (i.e. *@@@*) Otherwise accept every possible character including the characters in a delimiter pattern in the string (i.e. @*@@* would not split the string) Is this possible?

**EDITED Solution #2 Using regex (From @hwnd):**

Regex is not installed to python 2.7 if you are using that. You need to download and install this package. These are the explicit directions I took so you can do the same.

1. Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex and at the bottom of the page there are download links. Click on regex-2015.03.18-cp27-none-win32.whl  for Windows operating systems that are running Python 2.7 (Otherwise try other ones until a successful install works for you).
2. Browse to the download directory of the .whl file that you just downloaded. Shift+Right Click Anywhere in that directory and click on "Open command window here" and then type "pip install regex-2015.03.18-cp27-none-win32.whl" and should say "Successfully installed!"
3. You will now be able to use regex!

Here is the code:

```
import regex    
mystring = '@@@useradd---userfirstadd%ed###this is my username@!!!$$$hey whats up how are you??@@@useradd$$$This is my email @gmail.com!!!'
result = filter(None, regex.split(r'(?V1)(!!!)|\s*(?=(?:@|\$|#|-){3})', mystring)) 
print result
```

The result printed is as follows:

```
['@@@useradd', '---userfirstadd%ed', '###this is my username@', '!!!', '$$$hey whats up how are you??', '@@@useradd', '$$$This is my email @gmail.com', '!!!']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Since you want to retain all the characters between your pattern delimiters, you can do this using the [**regex**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, splitting on "!!!" and using lookahead for other zero-width matches.

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = '@@@useradd---userfirstadd%ed###this is my username@!!!$$$hey whats up how are you??@@@useradd$$$This is my email @gmail.com!!!'
>>> filter(None, regex.split(r'(?V1)(!!!)|\s*(?=(?:@|\$|#|-){3})', s))
['@@@useradd', '---userfirstadd%ed', '###this is my username@', '!!!', '$$$hey whats up how are you??', '@@@useradd', '$$$This is my email @gmail.com', '!!!']
```

Comment: This was perfect! I will be including directions to install the package for 2.7 above.

Answer (score 0):

use this regexp  if will provide 5 matching groups

(@{3}[a-z]+)(-{3}[a-z]+)(#{3}[a-z]+)(!{3})(\${3}[a-z]+)